# ROS node bridge for publish special topics over the internet

Tags: ros, node, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I want a ROS node bridge to subscribe some topics (on my ros machine) and publish them over the internet, to other node that listen this and publish this in another machine with ROS.

I want that each machine have a roscore running in an independent way.

Is there any tool or package to do this? or should I do my own node for each situation?

Regards,
Filipe

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46743/ros-node-bridge-for-publish-special-topics-over-the-internet/) by [Filipe Santos](https://answers.ros.org/users/907/filipe-santos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 346 on 2012-10-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure what you mean by an "independent way", but take a look at the [Multimaster SIG](http://ros.org/wiki/sig/Multimaster), and also (and likely more relevant for typical applications) the [Network Setup](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup) page on the wiki.

In both cases you'll have to make sure that the machines in question can communicate without issue in *both* directions.

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2012-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Filipe Santos](https://answers.ros.org/users/907/filipe-santos/) on 2012-10-25**:
thanks trinighost

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosbridge could be used for this purpose:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L-4TuNBiIRc

although multimaster maybe a better option for a ROS-to-ROS connection.

---

Originally posted by [odestcj](https://answers.ros.org/users/313/odestcj/) with karma: 123 on 2012-11-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2012-11-04**:
Does this option require both machines to be on the same (virtual private) network?

**Comment by [pacifica](https://answers.ros.org/users/1187/pacifica/) on 2012-12-04**:
Hi odestcj, can you tell me if rosbridge v1.0 is running on ros fuerte?? I've try to use it but i've several communication problems... in addition i think that the v2.0 of rosbridge not support socket communication.. but just websocket.